# How to disable required validation email User Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, spree, commerce

How to disable required validation email User Class on Spree Commerce?
I try to create a decorator:

```
Spree::User.class_eval do
  validates :email, :presence => false
end
```

With no success.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Still validating.
The required message still showing.
Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
Spree::User.class_eval do
    _validators.reject!{ |key, _| key == :email }

    _validate_callbacks.each do |callback|
        callback.raw_filter.attributes.delete :email if   callback.raw_filter.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator)
    end
end
```

Works!
Thank you for all.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use the `absence` instead of `presence`.?

`validates :email, absence: true`

or simple solution can comment out the validation code from your user model, but it leads to inconsistency into your db.